# Location latitude and longitude are different in android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, cllocationmanager, userlocation

Im using location manager to get the user current location.When I used the same latitude and longitude in google maps it is showing completely different location map with some km in difference and it is not at-least near to the exact location. But for android it is showing correctly. Following is my code snippet. Current location is India

```
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
    didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    userLocation = locations.last?.coordinate
    locationDelegate?.updateUserLocation(location: userLocation)
     }
```

Comment: Uncomment this line:- `locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`. Now check weather it is showing accurate result or not.

Comment: I have tried uncommenting the same but the same result.thanks